# how to interpret this t result?

Tags: statistical-significance, mathematical-statistics, t-test, inference, psychometrics

Two Sample t-test

```
data:  Data by Sex
t = -2.4583, df = 222, p-value = 0.9926
alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is greater than 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 -4.16643      Inf
sample estimates:
mean in group female   mean in group male 
            57.78070             60.27273
```

Answer (score 5):

You used a one-sided $t$-test to test against the null that

$$\text{H}_0: \mu_\text{women} \leq \mu_\text{men},$$

but you observed $\hat{y}_\text{men} \approx 57.8$ and $\hat{y}_\text{women} \approx 60.3$.

Therefore, you have very weak evidence against the null (in fact, your evidence points to the contrary), so you cannot reject it ($p \approx 0.993$).

Comment: @Alexis With no further details given in the question, it is not unlikely this new user simply didn't understand the syntax descriptions of `'greater'` and `'less'`. But fine, I'll remove it